# Input keyword & hit Enter key to get result from mysql

Tags: php, ajax

here is an idea to select ID from combo box & then it will automatically print data in html form field so that the field can be edit easily. i have 2 files so far- index.html & showData.php. here is the index.html file:

```
<html>

<head>

    <script>

        function showData(str)
        {
            if (str=="")
            {
                document.getElementById("ajax-content").innerHTML="";
                return;
            } 

            // Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }

            // Code for IE6, IE5
            else
            {
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("ajax-content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","showData.php?id="+str,true);

            xmlhttp.send();
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

<form>

<select name="register" onchange="showData(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select ID:</option>
        <option value="001">001</option>
        <option value="002">002</option>
        <option value="003">003</option>
    </select>   

</form>

<div id="ajax-content"></div>

</body>
```

and here is my showData.php file:

```
<?php

    // Receive variable from URI
    $id=$_GET["id"];

    // Connect to your database
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Select your database
    mysql_select_db("test_01", $con);

    // Select all fields from your table
    $sql="SELECT * FROM staffdetails WHERE id = '".$id."'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        echo "Staff Name:" . "<input type='text' value='" . $row['name'] . "'>";
        echo "</br>";
        echo "Contact No.:" . "<input type='text' value='" . $row['number'] . "'>";
    }

    // Close the connection
    mysql_close($con);

?>
```

now, what i'm trying to do is to type ID into form field (*rather than 'select from list'*) and press enter (**without having any 'submit' button**) to get the result on the form's field. anyone can help please?

Answer (score 1):

#### Give this in the `onkeyup` attribute.

```
<input onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) showData(this.value); return false;" />
```

#### Explanation

The `event` is current event happening for the `input`. When `keyup` event happens, it has a property called `keyCode`, which returns the ASCII code of the pressed key. The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key has a code `13`. When you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, this even happens.

Comment: thanks for reply :)

i replaced the combo box code with your code but it gives no output :( any other modification needed? do i need to set form's action??

Comment: @Atiqur Can you update it in the question? The whole updated source code?

Comment: sorry for late reply and also thanks for your help. the code is working now. in the index file, i remove <form> tag and then put this code 

'<body>
<p>Please Enter Your Staff ID:</p>
 <div><input onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) showData(this.value); return false;" /></div>
<div id="ajax-content"></div>
</body>'


now i want to ask you, is it possible to add a submit button after retrieve data & then save the data again to another sql table?